# Waterfall join in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, join

How can I best do a waterfall join in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.col1=B.col1 AND
   A.col2=B.col2
```

but for the ones where there's no match only join on col1 and ignore col2:

```
LEFT JOIN B
   ON A.col1=B.col1 AND
```

Comment: "Waterfall" join ...?

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of a waterfall join, but based on your description:

```
SELECT A.*, COALESCE(B.col3, C.col3) AS col3 ...
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B
    ON A. col1 = B.col1
    AND A.col2 = B.col2
  LEFT JOIN B AS C
    ON A.col1 = C.col1
    AND B.col1 IS NULL;
```